# How can I name the relationship between two records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Let's say I have a model `Movie`. Movies can have_many of each other through an intermediary model `AssociatedMovie`.

How can I specify the nature of the relationship between two Movies? For any given pair of Movies, the relationship may be prequel/sequel, or remake/original, or inspired/inspired by, or related/related, etc. Right now, I can't give the relationships names.

Here's my schema and associations:

```
create_table "movies", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
end

create_table "associated_movies", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "movie_a_id"
  t.integer  "movie_b_id"
end


class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies, :through => :associated_movies
end

class AssociatedMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies
end
```

And here's the query for setting each Movie's associated Movies:

```
def movie_associated_movies
  associated_movie_ids = AssociatedMovie.
      where("movie_a_id = ? OR movie_b_id = ?", self.id, self.id).
      map { |r| [r.movie_a_id, r.movie_b_id] }.
      flatten - [self.id]
  Movie.where(id: associated_movie_ids)
end
```

I think I'd probably have to add `movie_a_type` and `movie_b_type` attributes to `AssociatedMovie`. But I'm not sure how I could specify which Movie is attached to which type.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already half-way there with [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) (using an intermediary model) - this allows you to add as many extra attributes as you like.

I think your problem is down to your relationships, which I'll explain below:

---

```
#app/models/movie.rb
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :associated_movies, foreign_key: :movie_a_id
   has_many :movies, through: :associated_movies, foreign_key: :movie_b_id
end

#app/models/associated_movie.rb
class AssociatedMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :movie_a, class_name: "Movie"
   belongs_to :movie_b, class_name: "Movie"
end
```

The above will give you access to:

```
@movie = Movie.find params[:id]
@movie.associated_movies #-> collection of records with movie_a and movie_b

@movie.movies #-> all the movie_b objects
```

--

Because you're using `has_many :through`, [rather than `has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many), you'll be at liberty to add as many attributes to your join model as you need:

[image]

To do this, you just have to add a migration:

```
$ rails g migration AddNewAttributes

#db/migrate/add_new_attributes_________.rb
class AddNewAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :associated_movies, :relationship_id, :id
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

-

... I apologize if this is a little off-course; however I would actually add a separate model for your relationships (considering you have them predefined):

```
#app/models/relationship.rb
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    #columns id | movie_a_type | movie_b_type | created_at | updated_at
    has_many :associated_movies
end

#app/models/associated_movie.rb
class AssociatedMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :movie_a, class_name: "Movie"
    belongs_to :movie_b, class_name: "Movie"

    belongs_to :relationship
    delegate :movie_a_type, :movie_b_type, to: :relationship
end
```

This may seem a little bloated (it is), but it will provide extensibility.

You'll have to add another table, but it will ultimately provide you with the ability to call the following:

```
@movie.associated_movies.each do |associated|
   associated.movie_a #-> current movie
   associated.movie_b #-> related movie
   associated.movie_a_type #-> "Original"
   associated.movie_b_type #-> "Sequel"
end
```

You'd then be able to pre-populate the `Relationship` model with the various relationships you'll have.

I can add to the answer as required.